# How to modify parts of an element, when its inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The original div is pretty large, so basically here is a trimmed down version. I have a div that i clone into another div, every time a button is pressed.

```
<div id="demo_variation">
    <div>
        <h4 class="panel-title">
           <span class="title">Product Variation</span>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="all_variations">

</div>
```

Now when someone clicks a button i want to clone #demo_variation into #all_variation but also need to change things like id and title. 
**Ideally what i want is to do something like this.**

```
var newVariation = $('#demo_variation').html();
newVariation.find('#demo_variation').attr('id', 'product_variation_1');
newVariation.find('.title').text('Product Variation 1');
```

But for some reason this doesn't work. Am i doing this wrong??

Comment: Why aren't you using `.clone()`? I also don't see `newVariation.find('#demo_variation')` working.

Comment: `html()` returns a string. Start with `var newVariation = $('#demo_variation').clone();` instead.

Comment: Thanks guys, i did try clone before and i thought it didn't work. Turns out i was cloning a hidden div :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clone()` like this:

```js
var count = 0;
$('button').on('click',function(){
  var cont=$('#demo_variation').clone().prop('id','new'+count);
  $('#all_variations').append(cont);
  $('#all_variations .title').last().text('New Title'+count)
  count++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo_variation">
    <div>
        <h4 class="panel-title">
           <span class="title">Product Variation</span>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="all_variations">
</div>
<button>Append New</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you need to clone the div using `.clone()` and then change the property of the cloned object.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var cloneObj = $("#demo_variation").clone();
  $(cloneObj).attr("id", "product_variation_1");
  $(cloneObj).find("span.title").text("Product Variation 1");
  $("body").append($(cloneObj)[0].outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo_variation">
  <div>
    <h4 class="panel-title">
               <span class="title">Product Variation</span>
            </h4>
  </div>
</div>
<button>
  Clone
</button>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/482fhmmv/